# Put pretty_print() on dash application

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, plotly-dash

I want to show the sentence structure on the dash application. I failed to write it inside "".format(), which is the only way I can show the output on the website. I can use pretty_print() to show the structure but pretty_print() only shows on the console, not on the website.

```
# NLP result
Parse = '(ROOT\n  (S\n    (NP (DT This))\n    (VP (VBZ is)\n      (NP (DT a) (NN test) (NN message)))\n    (. .)))'

# output code
def output_nlp(Json_data, tokn, Pos, Ner, Parse, Dep_parse):
    parse_tree = ParentedTree.fromstring(Parse)
    parse_tree.pretty_print()
    return "NLP Parse: \n {}".format(Parse)
```

I tried to put parse_tree.pretty_print() after return, it won't work. Does anyone have any ideas how to show the pretty_print() on the website. It's ok if you don't use pretty_print(), I just want to show something like:
[example output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t37KT.png)

Answer (score 0):

We can take a look at [the source code of `nltk`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/) to find out how `pretty_print()` works. [The definition of `pretty_print`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/1de3be80680b485e007bd6f944549730181693e9/nltk/tree.py#L752-L760) is as follows:

```
def pretty_print(self, sentence=None, highlight=(), stream=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Pretty-print this tree as ASCII or Unicode art.
    For explanation of the arguments, see the documentation for
    `nltk.treeprettyprinter.TreePrettyPrinter`.
    """
    from nltk.treeprettyprinter import TreePrettyPrinter

    print(TreePrettyPrinter(self, sentence, highlight).text(**kwargs), file=stream)
```

Therefore, we see that the function is creating a `TreePrettyPrinter` object ([defined here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/1de3be80680b485e007bd6f944549730181693e9/nltk/treeprettyprinter.py#L44-L583), and printing the result from calling its `text()` method.

In your code, you want to be able to `return` the text that is printed by `pretty_print` instead of printing it. Therefore, you will have to replicate this `TreePrettyPrinter` object. [The initialiser method of the `TreePrettyPrinter` object](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/1de3be80680b485e007bd6f944549730181693e9/nltk/treeprettyprinter.py#L72) has the following arguments:

```
def __init__(self, tree, sentence=None, highlight=()):
```

Only `tree` is required; `sentence` and `highlight` are optional. Comparing this to the code in `pretty_print()`, you see that `sentence` and `highlight` are also predefined in `pretty_print`, and set to the same default value. You are not changing these values in your code, so you can ignore these arguments.

Furthermore, `pretty_print()` gives the option to provide additional keyword arguments, which are passed on to the `text()` method of the `TreePrettyPrinter`. You are not providing any, so you can ignore those as well. Therefore, you only have to provide the `tree` argument to the `TreePrettyPrinter`. Using this information, you can create a `TreePrettyPrinter` object, call its `text()` method, and return the result in your code as follows:

```
from nltk.treeprettyprinter import TreePrettyPrinter

def output_nlp(Json_data, tokn, Pos, Ner, Parse, Dep_parse):
    parse_tree = ParentedTree.fromstring(Parse)
    pretty_tree = TreePrettyPrinter(parse_tree).text()
    return "NLP Parse: \n {}".format(pretty_tree)
```